# Get a rails record matching given parameters that is closest to a different record in ascending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a model:

```
the_model
    :string_one
    :string_two
    :boolean_flag
    :other_fields_I_can't_use_to_search
```

and given that I have one record of that model already

```
model id: 12, string_one: "test 1", string_two: "test 2", boolean_flag: false
```

is there a way to get a record of the model with the same string parameters, and different flag, that is closest to the initial record, searching in ascending order?

I need the closest one because these records come in pairs, but there can be more than one set of pairs so I cant simply search for the other matching one

edit:

sample database:

```
id: 1, string_one: "test1", string_two: "test2":, boolean_flag: false
id: 2, string_one: "test3", string_two: "test4":, boolean_flag: false
id: 3, string_one: "test1", string_two: "test2":, boolean_flag: true
id: 4, string_one: "test5", string_two: "test6":, boolean_flag: false
id: 5, string_one: "test1", string_two: "test2":, boolean_flag: false
id: 6, string_one: "test3", string_two: "test4":, boolean_flag: true
id: 7, string_one: "test1", string_two: "test2":, boolean_flag: true
id: 8, string_one: "test5", string_two: "test6":, boolean_flag: true
id: 9, string_one: "test1", string_two: "test2":, boolean_flag: false
id: 10, string_one: "test1", string_two: "test2":, boolean_flag: true
```

I need to find the pair to record 7, which in this case is record 5.
I need to not get either record 9 or record 1

Comment: do you mean something like: `model id: 13, string_one: "test 1", string_two: "test 2", boolean_flag: true`

Comment: Yes, those are the parameters I am looking for, however there could be multiple entries that match those parameters (except :id) and I need the one that has the closest id to the initial entry

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to achieve this with a method in your model as such:

```
the_model
  def nearest_pair
   self.class.where(string_one: string_one, string_two: string_two, boolean_flag: !boolean_flag).order(id: :asc).first
# by default AR#first would order by the primary key column(id) in ascending order though
  end
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Wouldn't that simply return the first instance with those properties in the table though?

Comment: Yes, per the question, you said `same string parameter`, but `different flag`, so the flag should be negated. However you could also attach a `where.not(id: id)`

Comment: I'm not trying to return the first instance of it though, there can be multiple entries that match those parameters, I need the one that has the closest index to the original record, per the title

Comment: I think you're confusing me more, could you provide an example, and an expectation. From the question and several clarifications, you mentioned that you needed the closest pair with a different flag, which I've tried to provide so far. Or how are you currently implementing it?

Comment: I added a table sample and more explicitly indicated what fields I needed